# Devise - auth_token and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, auth-token

I'm using Rails 3.0 and Devise 1.1.7. In order to develop some API behavior, I enabled the TokenAuthentication functionality.

The thing is, when I try to access with an auth_token parameter, the current_user is not being set properly.
Should it? Or am I missing something?

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to the user model:

```
before_save :ensure_authentication_token
```

This will ensure an authentication token exists (creating one if not) before you save your user. There is also a `reset_authentication_token` if you want to change it.